# Is it possible to call functions from parent directive controller, when subsidiary directive has isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here is the [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/56GNC/) exemplifying my situation.

```
app=angular.module("app",[]);

app.directive("submitForm",function(){
    return{
        scope:{},
        restrict: 'A',
        controller:function($scope, $element){
            $scope.submitted=false;

            this.submit=function(){
                $scope.submitted=true;
            };
            this.getSubmit=function(){
                return $scope.submitted;
            };
            this.submitOn=function(){
                return $scope.$broadcast("submitOn");
            };
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,ctrl){
            element.find("button").on("click",function(){
                scope.submitted=true;
                ctrl.submitOn();
            });
        }
    }
})
.directive('errorRender',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        //scope: {},
        require:['ngModel','^submitForm'],
        controller: function($scope, $element){
            $scope.$broadcast("requireErrorEnable");

            $scope.$broadcast("requireErrorDisable");

            $scope.$broadcast("maxlengthErrorEnable");

            $scope.$broadcast("maxlengthErrorDisable");
        },
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {

            return function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                modelCtrl=ctrl[0];
                formCtrl=ctrl[1];

                scope.$on("submitOn",function(){
                    alert("submitOn!!!");
                });

                scope.$on("requireErrorEnable",function(){
                    element.attr("placeholder","error");
                });

                scope.$on("requireErrorDisable",function(){
                    element.attr("placeholder","");
                });

                scope.$watch(function(scope){
                        return ctrl[0].$error.required;
                    },
                    function(newValue, oldValue, scope){
                        if(ctrl[0].$error.required){
                            if((ctrl[0].$dirty && !ctrl[0].$viewValue)){
                                scope.$emit("requireErrorEnable");
                            }
                        }else{
                            scope.$emit("requireErrorDisable");
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If I use the directive **errorRender** in an isolated scope, I can't fire the function **submitForm** of the directive's controller in this case. Otherwise all directives **errorRender** fire at the same time (as we can expect).

Comment: You are saying you want to call the child directive's functions from the parent directive given an isolated scope?

Comment: No. I want to call the parent directive's functions from the child directive 
`scope.$on("submitOn",function(){
     alert("submitOn!!!");
});`

Answer (score 0):

directives can share controllers via the `require` property, that you correctly specified. this is what [Angular's docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) on directives say about accessing the directive's controller (emphasis added):

"`require` - Require another directive and **inject its controller as the fourth argument to the linking function**. The require takes a string name (or **array of strings**) of the directive(s) to pass in. **If an array is used, the injected argument will be an array in corresponding order**. If no such directive can be found, or if the directive does not have a controller, then an error is raised"

IMHO, when applied to your case, this means that the link function where the controller is injected is the one in your child directive, not in the parent